# How do i check if an app is currently running?

Tags: java, android

im trying to check if a certain app is running or not but i dont seem to be able to. (Am i missing something obvious? im not too experienced with android so i might have missed something).

in order to debug if it is working i wrote this in the onCreate (keep in mind this app is just a test and not an actual project so the code is running in a constant while loop):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        while (true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SIZE IS" + runningAppProcessInfo.size());
            runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        }
```

it gave a size of 1 which was my app, even if other apps are running - which is obviously not ideal.. any idea why? what am i doing wrong? thanks :)

Comment: That approach has not worked in several years, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare damn.. do you know if there is any way to do this then?

Comment: In real time, I hope not, for privacy and security reasons.